# How to upload image post method in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

**HTML**

```
 <form #productForm="ngForm" ngSubmit)="createNewProduct(productForm)">
   <div class="form-group ">
      <input   type="file" [(ngModel)]="model.files" name="files" #files="ngModel" class="form-control"  id="files"  multiple="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="productname">Name</label>          
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productname" required minlength="5" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9/,-. ]*$" maxlength="30"  [(ngModel)]="model.productname" name="productname" #productname="ngModel">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
           <label for="sales">Sales price/rate</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sales" pattern="[0-9]+" required minlength="0" maxlength="10"  [(ngModel)]="model.sales" name="sales" #sales="ngModel">
       </div>
```

Submit

**component.ts**

```
    createNewProduct(productForm: NgForm) {      
         this.productService.save_user(json).subscribe(response => console.log('Inserted Successfully'),
      error => console.log(error));
  }
```

**service.ts**

```
  save_user(product_data: any): Observable<any[]> {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
    };
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/product/', product_data, httpOptions)
        .map(response => response)
        .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.statusText));
};
```

Here i have mentioned my component.ts and service.ts, and my Html. i dont how to upload image.

Comment: You can use form data to upload files in angular 2.

Comment: "Here is what I tried so far" and what isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. In your service method create a new formData object and append your files to it. And then you can use http.post method to send that to backend.

```
public uploadFile(file: File, otherData: any): Observable<any> {

  let formData:FormData = new FormData();  
  formData.append('document',file);
  formData.append('name',otherData.name);
  formData.append('age',otherData.name);  

  return this.http.post("/your/url",formData)  
            .map((response: Response) => {  
              return response;                 
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply .  Already i have created service layer. Actually i am new to Angular2 so could u please tell me where to add this .

Comment: yeah sure.. Add this method to your product service. And call this method from createNewProduct method.

Comment: Actually  i'm having doubt along  with that  image i want to sent data like product_name and sale.

Comment: You can append fields to the formData object. I will update the answer.

Comment: I have tried it  and having doubt that Already im using save_user in service layer. what i did was i removed my service layer and pasted what u have given but it showing  500 internal error.

Comment: in **service** layer.public uploadFile(file: File, productForm: any): Observable<any> {

        let formData:FormData = new FormData();  
        formData.append('document',file);
        formData.append('pro_name',productForm.pro_name);
        formData.append('description',productForm.description);  
        return this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/product/",formData)  
                  .map((response: Response) => {  
                    return response;                 
                  });
      }
i dont whether i have did correct or not?.

Comment: Not able to upload image. it showing 500 internal server error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169219/discussion-between-anuradha-gunasekara-and-sudharsan-venkatraj).

Comment: You should handle that in your backend.